# Additional where in laravel query builder

Tags: php, laravel, query-builder

I have joined table in my query but i need to validate the value of column in that table, it returns

```
 SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'on' in 'on clause'
```

## Code

```
$interests = DB::table('projects')
->where('projects.published', 'y')
->whereDate('projects.created_at', Carbon::now()->subDay())
->join('project_tag', 'project_tag.project_id', '=', 'projects.id') //get project tags


->join('mailings', 'mailings.interests', '=', 'on') //get mailing lists with on value in interests column


->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'mailings.user_id') //get mailing users
->join('user_interests', 'user_interests.user_id', '=', 'users.id') //get mailing users intrests (same as tags in projects)
->select('projects.*', 'users.*')
->get();
```

my issue is in this line

```
->join('mailings', 'mailings.interests', '=', 'on')
```

I just want to join `mailings` where their `intrests` column value is set to `on`

Any idea?

## Update

I changed my issued line to:

```
->join('mailings', function ($join) {
  $join->where('mailings.interests', '=', 'on');
})
```

now it's returning results but output data are duplicated and not complete. here is what i get on `dd`

```
lluminate\Support\Collection {#819     
 #items: array:6 [                     
   0 => {#824                          
     +"title": "test 1"                
     +"slug": "test-1"                 
     +"budget": 23454235.0             
     +"name": "Diana Bosco"            
     +"email": "arunolfsson@example.net
   }                                   
   1 => {#827                          
     +"title": "test 1"                
     +"slug": "test-1"                 
     +"budget": 23454235.0             
     +"name": "Diana Bosco"            
     +"email": "arunolfsson@example.net
   }                                   
   2 => {#820                          
     +"title": "test 1"                
     +"slug": "test-1"                 
     +"budget": 23454235.0             
     +"name": "admin"                 
     +"email": "admin@admin.com"       
   }                                   
   3 => {#826                          
     +"title": "test 1"                
     +"slug": "test-1"                 
     +"budget": 23454235.0             
     +"name": "admin"                 
     +"email": "admin@admin.com"       
   }                                   
   4 => {#823                          
     +"title": "test 1"                
     +"slug": "test-1"                 
     +"budget": 23454235.0             
     +"name": "Aurelia Treutel I"      
     +"email": "korey13@example.net"   
   }                                   
   5 => {#825                          
     +"title": "test 1"                
     +"slug": "test-1"                 
     +"budget": 23454235.0             
     +"name": "Aurelia Treutel I"      
     +"email": "korey13@example.net"   
   }                                   
 ]
```

## issues

1. Data are duplicated for each user
2. It gets same project for all users while it should be different based on their tags.

**To be clear** `Logic`

1. I my users have tags (i called it interests)
2. Projects have tags as well
3. I want to get projects that have same tags as user interests and show them to user.
4. List item

Comment: What do you means 'value is set to on' ?

Comment: @IjasAmeenudeen `where('mailings.interests', '=', 'on')`

Comment: 'on' is a value in your table ?

Comment: yes..it's checkbox value or is `on` or `off`

Answer (score 0):

Use `->join()` to join the `mailings` table via FK reference, same as you have done for the other tables, then change the `where` clause to an array of conditions:

```
->where([
    ['projects.published', '=', 'y'],
    ['mailings.interests', '=', 'on'],
])
```

Comment: hi, i did this is it ok? `->join('mailings', function ($join) {
            $join->where('mailings.interests', '=', 'on');
        })`

Answer (score 0):

Apply the filter as,

```
$interests = DB::table('projects')
            ->where('projects.published', 'y')
            ->whereDate('projects.created_at', Carbon::now()->subDay())
            ->join('project_tag', 'project_tag.project_id', '=', 'projects.id') //get project tags

            // the filter
            ->where('mailings.interests', 'on')

            ->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'mailings.user_id') //get mailing users
            ->join('user_interests', 'user_interests.user_id', '=', 'users.id') //get mailing users intrests (same as tags in projects)
            ->select('projects.*', 'users.*')
            ->get();
```

Comment: `mailings` doesn't have `project_id` column it's belong to user only

Comment: as you see i just related mailings to my users join nowhere else